# returning List<Object> from Mono DLL

Tags: c#, linux, list, mono, .net-assembly

I have a project - ASP.NET portal coded/built on Mono/Linux. I have recently moved from using a class from the project for a [nearly] identical version of the class from inside a DLL assembly.
Used to get a collection of initialized objects, and now I get nulls. Is this because my class is now inside a DLL? Is there a problem passing List as a return type from a method inside an assembly?
What can it be, and more importantly can should I do?

Thank you

Comment: Add one or more snippets of code and elaborate the question somewhat more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a someone who refactored my messing this up in a very unconventional way. There is no problem passing arrays.
It is perplexing to see that such an innocent question drew so many haters.